# What email server should I choose?

Tags: email, debian, postfix, debian-etch

I need a secure email server installed in debian-lenny with users in a mysql table.
Also users are from multiple domains.
Quota should be in mysql or a global variable for all users.
What are my options ? 
THanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What protocols and features do you need it to support?

Comment: Only incoming smtp port 25

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you want your users to be able to access their received mails. So you'll need at least a POP3 or an IMAP server.

Answer (score 5):

I run the following software on Debian Etch without any problems:

- Postfix
- Potstfixadmin
- MySQL
- Dovecot (courier etc will probably also work, but Iv'e found dovecot to be much slimmer on resources and easier to set up)

Gives you virtual users and domains, vacation messages, imap(s), pop3(s), web-based user/alias/domain managment etc. Highly recommended.

Edit: Here's a tutorial aswell - http://bliki.rimuhosting.com/space/knowledgebase/linux/mail/postfixadmin+on+debian+sarge

Answer (score 2):

I pretty much followed this guide: http://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-users-domains-postfix-courier-mysql-squirrelmail-debian-lenny

Does what you require.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a huge QMAIL fan.  It hasn't had a security issue ever.  The toaster makes it easier to throw a box up if you're less familiar with it.

- [QMAIL Toaster](http://www.qmailtoaster.com/)
- [QMAIL Security](http://cr.yp.to/qmail/guarantee.html)

Comment: Ditto for me.  There are some great tutorials that can be found at qmail.org in the documentation section.  Also, Life With Qmail, by Dave Sill http://lifewithqmail.org/ is a great resource.

Comment: I like Qmail aswell, but the patching of code (wich violates qmail's security guarantee) got to me, so I changed to Postfix.

Answer (score 1):

Although I like installing and configuring the different components of a complete mail system myself, you might be interested in [iRedMail](http://code.google.com/p/iredmail/) which is basically a script installing and configuring every needed component for you. It also brings a [web interface](http://www.iredmail.org/admin_panel.html) for configuration.

Answer (score 0):

postfix-policyd for your rate limiting/throttling

http://packages.debian.org/lenny/postfix-policyd
http://policyd.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Courier has the complete suite (MTA, POP3, IMAP) that all can share the same authentication-system (single configuration for validating against a database). I'm not sure about quota though.

If you mix systems (psotfix + courier for example), you will need to setup them indvidually for the same database-schema.

Answer (score 0):

Use Postfix, with virtual-domains.